# Re-run a python script after a few days if it fails

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

Assuming a script fails and it is captured in a try catch how to run a python script again after a few days?

I can use `sleep` on this problem, but I think it will not work due to the fact that the server restarts every day. What is the best solution on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you want to address this with a cron job.

I would probably do the following:

1. When the python file runs, save a log file with the status date/time.
2. Set up a cron job on the server to check, say once every 24 hours, that checks that log file and either do nothing or runs the python file again.